# unlink(): Invalid argument this error is occurred while update image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to update image to image/brand/ folder but unexpectedly error is occurred.

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'brand_name' => 'required|max:4',
            // 'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        ]);

        $old_image=$request->old_image;
        $brandimage=$request->file('brand_image');

        $image_gen=hexdec(uniqid());
        $image_exten=strtolower($brandimage->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $image_name=$image_gen.'.'.$image_exten;
        $image_location='image/brand/';
        $image_uplioad= $image_location.$image_name;

        $brandimage->move($image_location,$image_name);

        unlink($old_image);

        Brand::find($id)->update([
            'brand_name' =>$request->brand_name,
            'brand_image'=>$image_uplioad,
            'Created_at'=> Carbon::Now()
        ]);

        return  Redirect()->back()->with('success','Brand image updated Successfully');


    }
```

> ErrorException
> unlink(): Invalid argument this is the error what i got i need over come this problem please help

Comment: What does `print_r($old_image)` show you? Does the file exist at that (string) location?

Answer (score 1):

You could optimize it by update the image from model by creating `updateImage` method inside the **model** like this

### Brand Model

```
.....
    public function updateImage($image)
    {
        $oldImage = $this->brand_image?? '';
      
        $this->brand_image = $image->store('brand', 'public');

        $this->save();

        Storage::disk('public')->delete($oldImage);
    }
.....
```

after that the controller will be like this

```php
  $validated = $request->validate([
        'brand_name' => 'required|max:4',
        // 'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    $brand = Brand::find($id)->update([
        'brand_name' =>$request->brand_name,
        'Created_at'=> Carbon::Now()
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('brand_image'))
        $brand->updateImage($request->file('brand_image'));

    return  Redirect()->back()->with('success','Brand image updated Successfully');
```

Comment: You should change it to store the file first. so when an exception occurs, you dont delete the old image for nothing.

Comment: I think it is impossible to have an exception in this part

Comment: @N69S, check it again i update it

Answer (score 0):

please pass the `$old_image=$request->old_image;` value from in blade.